# Net Core MemoryCache not resetting per request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memorycache

.Net Core 3.0. I have a repo where IMemoryCache gets injected. Repo is registered as Transient. I would like for the cache to be cleared/reset PER request, however that is not happening. It keeps data inserted there from prev request. How do I make it so that MemoryCache is re-created per request?

```
public OrganizationRepository(
   IMemoryCache cache)
{
    m_cache = cache;
    // cache still has data in entries for subsequent requests
}
```

Registrations:

```
services.AddTransient<IOrganizationRepository, OrganizationRepository>();
```

Comment: I don't know why you use IMemoryCache to store a data per Request? Because Cache is a technique which helps to reduce number of database round-trip in many requests, not specific one request. There are some techniques which can help your situation such as  HttpContext.Items or writing your Context via custom middleware.

Comment: A per request injected cache doesn't make sense. A new controller is created for each request. So what would you cache inside one request?

Comment: @JohnathanLe, in my instance i'm doing inserting a bunch of rows (single request), i would like to store stuff in cache during that one request/per request. I'm looking to do 'short lived cache', hence per request cache usage

Comment: @ShaneKm so just put them into HttpContext.Items and get whenever you want. Cache isn't introduced to use in one request, Cache instance is a Singleton actually. If HttpContext.Items isn't suitable for your idea, just write custom middleware, inject your custom context and add as much as you want.

Comment: IMemoryCache is registered by default I believe, and is always registrered as singleton, mostly because it seems to be designed for such usage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1 <- see "Caution" section here.

Comment: @Evk, i'm using .net core, not System.Runtime.Caching

Comment: Then are you registering it somehow? Because how repository is registered is not very relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
services.AddScoped<MemoryCache, MemoryCache>();
```

then inject it as MemoryCache

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own memory cache easily.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, List<Product>> _localCache = new Dictionary<string, List<Product>>();

public async Task<List<Product>> LocalListAsync(bool invalidateCache = false)
{
    const string cacheKey = "ProductList";
    if (invalidateCache)
    {
        _localCache.Remove(cacheKey);
    }

    if (_localCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out var list))
    {
        return list;
    }

    await _products
        .Include(x => x.ProductCategory)
        .LoadAsync();

    list = _products.Local.ToList();
    _localCache.Add(cacheKey, list);
    return list;
}
```